# How to hide the link for creating certain content type?

Tags: nodes, users

I am trying to make a reservation system for equipment in a laboratory. People reserve equipment by creating "reservation" nodes. Some fields in the reservation node already have values, determined by the way the (registered) users reached the "form", and the values can´t be changed by them.
I don´t want the registered users to have access to create the reservation node through the "Add content -> Create Reservation node" way.
How to "hide" that option in the add content menu? (as they do have permission to create the reservation node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simply get rid of link, you can go to http://example.com/admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation (substitute example with your domain) and remove the entry. This will not block direct access to http://example.com/node/add/reservation - if you are using custom module for that, consider blocking node creation in http://example.com/admin/people/permissions - your module can create nodes for them even when you remove "create node ... " permission there.

Comment: If I disable or move a create content link from the navigataion menu I get this error when I then try to directly access that node add form: "You have not created any content types yet."

Comment: @rooby if you have any content types, it's some Kong of bug. If you don't, it was a big that you was able to create content. Anyway, it's a matter for another question or bug report.

Comment: Seemingly it is possibly related to this: https://www.drupal.org/node/550254

Comment: @rooby well, major core bug is out of scope of my answer... Anyway, all I suggested was removing only one content type entry, not a whole node/add, so if someone will do what I wore and only what I wrote, he's safe.

Comment: It also happens when you move just an individual item. You're right it doesn't really affect your answer but it might useful info to someone else that sees this.

Comment: @rooby Moving one item never did anything bad for me. Don't know, didn't try it on the recent version.

Answer (score 3):

In drupal 8, you can remove certain links from the /node/add page hook_preprocess_node_add_list():

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node_add_list(&$vars) {

  // Remove a few content types from /node/add page.
  $types_to_remove = [
    'dog',
    'cat',
    'fox',
    'rabbit',
  ];
  foreach ($types_to_remove as $type) {
    unset($vars['content'][$type]);
    unset($vars['types'][$type]);
  }
}
```

If you are using the admin_toolbar for drop-downs, you can remove links using hook_menu_links_discovered_alter().

```
function mymodule_menu_links_discovered_alter(&$links) {

  // Remove a few "node add" pages from admin menu.
  $types_to_remove = [
    'dog',
    'cat',
    'fox',
    'rabbit',
  ];
  foreach ($types_to_remove as $type) {
    unset($links['node.add.' . $type]);
  }
}
```